# How to reduce image channels

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

How to reduce lable_image channels from 18_channels to 7_channels(7classes)?

I try to convert label one-hot then return to custom_data_generator,but I think I should adjust channels before convert one-hot

My image are 5 * 1channels & 1 * 3_channels,I want to concatenate them to 8_channels but connot concatenate on 1channel so I spread them to 3_channels and concatenate to 18_channels .npy file,label image do same action.

```
ValueError
could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,18,7) into shape (512,512,7)
  File "C:\Labbb\testing\unet_mao0\data.py", line 232, in get_data
    y[i,] = label_one_hot
  File "C:\Labbb\testing\unet_mao0\data.py", line 193, in __getitem__
    return self.get_data(batch)
  File "C:\Labbb\testing\unet_mao0\main.py", line 105, in <module>
    train_history=model.fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=30,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,18,7) into shape (512,512,7)
```

```
    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_classes))

        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):

            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)
            
            min_val = label.min()
            max_val = label.max()
            scaled_label = (label - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)  # Scale to [0, 1]
            scaled_label = (scaled_label * (self.n_classes - 1)).astype(int)  # Scale to [0, n_classes-1]

            label_one_hot = to_categorical(scaled_label, num_classes=self.n_classes)
            
            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = label_one_hot
```